# code for finding the largest element in the array is at least twice as much as every other number in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I was writing the code for finding the largest element in the array is at least twice as much as every other number in the array.

Output the index(0-based) of the largest element if the condition holds true or -1 otherwise.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int [] x = new int [n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            x[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        
        int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int count=0;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(max<x[i]){
                max=x[i];
                count=0;
            }
            if(max==x[i]){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count>=2){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("-1");
        }
    }
}
```

In my case the test cases from hackerrank are not passing can someone please guide me here so as to pass all the test cases.

Comment: Can you explain where in your code you tried to check if the maximum number is twice as big as the next biggest number? To me it just looks like you iterate over the array and count how often the biggest number appears in the array with the `count` variable and if it appears twice you print it, otherwise you print -1. But that has little to do with the actual task description

Comment: if(max==x[i]) in this condition I am checking if the max element is occurring more than once then we will upgrade the count again for the maximum element.

Comment: Yes I understand that. What I don't understand is why you are doing this. Why are you counting how often the maximum element appears? If I understand your task description correct the task is to check if the maximum element in the array is at least 2 times bigger than every other number in the array. That has nothing to do with how often the element appears. Or do i misunderstand the task?

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, the element you are searching for can only be the maximum element in the array. Furthermore you only have to check whether this element is at least twice as big as second largest value. Ie find the indexes `x` and `y`  of the two largest elements in the array and check if `a[x] >= 2*a[y]`

```
int x = a[0] >= a[1] ? 0 : 1;
int y = a[0] < a[1] ? 0 : 1;

for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
  if (a[i] > a[x]) {
    //The current element is larger than the current maximum.
    //Thus, it becomes the new max, and the current max becomes second largest.
    y = x; x = i;
  } else if (a[i] > a[y]) {
    //The current element is larger than the second biggest but smaller than the maximum
    //Thus only replace the second biggest element 
    y = i;
  }
}
//Check if the maximum is at least twice as big as the second largest 
return (a[x] >= 2*a[y]) ? x : -1;
```